# Efficiently adding spaces behind multiple characters in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I currently have a string as follows:

```
[accept,#PID<0.395.0>,{id:N1,num:1},Appeltaart]
```

To improve readability I would like to add spaces behind the `,` and `:` characters. I know I can do this using the `replaceAll()` function twice, as follows:

```
someString.replaceAll(':', ': ').replaceAll(',', ', ')
```

But this doesn't seem efficient, especially if next time I wanted to add spaces behind 5 characters. Is there a more efficient approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: Use a regular expression to identify where you want to add spaces.

Comment: I can use a regular expression to identify all the points where I want to add spaces, but how do I then add the space while keeping the original character in tact? I do not want to simply replace the character, but add a space behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use regex for that, to add more characters to the list add them to the `re` variable:

```js
let str = '[accept,#PID<0.395.0>,{id:N1,num:1},Appeltaart]'

let re = /(,|:)/g

let result = str.replace(re,"$1 ")

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want, try this code and see if it work for you

```
let text = "[accept,#PID<0.395.0>,{id:N1,num:1},Appeltaart]";
let result = (text.replace(/,/g, ', ')).replace(/\:/g, ': ');
console.log(result); // output [accept, #PID<0.395.0>, {id: N1, num: 1}, Appeltaart]
```

Comment: the only way that makes it hard is */g* . if you use */i* instead, it should not work